# How to add a object (table entity) as the value and the key being one of the field from the table in a dictionary using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a table something similar to below:

```
tableName : Spec

Nbr  UserId   Value1  Value2   Value 3
---  ------- ------   -------  -------
1    111        abc    def       ghi
2    111        sed    uvw       xyz
3    111        ttt    sss       vvv
4    222        sed    uvw       xyz
5    222        abc    def       ghi
6    222        sed    uvw       xyz
7    333        sed    uvw       xyz
8    333        abc    def       ghi
9    333        sed    uvw       xyz
```

I am trying to add a new dictionary that can be

```
Dictionary<long, Spec[]> specs = new Dictionary<long, Spec[]>();
```

I want to add the userid in the above table as the Key which should be distinct and the whole table data for that Userid as the `Spec[]`.
from the above table, I should have only three keys with the `spec[]` attached to it.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Where are you have the table? In `DB`, in `DataTabe` or so? Which `DAL` are you use?

Comment: I have the table in Oracle Database. this table is of 4 million rows and I am trying to extract this into a CSV file. I thought dictinary is better for faster processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean grouping the specs by key, do this:

```
var dict = specs.GroupBy(i => i.UserId);
```

If you need it in a dictionary, then add:

```
.ToDictionary((k) => k.Key, (v) => v.ToList());
```

LINQ and Grouping is perfect for what you want to do, as it groups the results by a key.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that holds your fields.

```
public class Spec
{
    public int Nbr { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Put instances of that class in the Value portion of your dictionary entry.  Put whatever you want into the Key of the dictionary entry.

```
var spec = new Spec {Nbr = 1, UserID = 111, Value1 = "foo" }
dictionary.Add(Nbr, spec);
```

Comment: I have a entity class that looks similar like you mentioned. When I am trying to add the key to the dictinary. I am unable to add as the Userid is not unique.

Comment: You've either got to somehow make it unique, or use some data structure other than a dictionary.